# jQuery File Upload (blueimp) with zend framework 2 (zf2)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, zend-framework2

I am trying to implement jQuery File Upload (blueimp) with zend framework 2.

I put all the js and css files inside public folder and trying to upload the files inside public folder.  But unfortunately when I submit the Start upload button its giving below error

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

But my browser and server supports json, I have tested.

Its running fine when test for jQuery File Upload (blueimp) demo on my local server.

Please help me if you have any idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so what is the contents of the JSON data?

Comment: No Json and response I found with firebug.

Comment: Any body implemented blueimp with zf2 successfully? can I have one sample code or any help? Please help me, I am straggling to get it done. Thank you

Comment: still needs it?